# Modify child div id using parent div id

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change the div id of child using the parent div id, 
for example:

```
<div id="parent">  
    <div id = "child">  
    </div>  
</div>
```

tried few things:

```
$('#parent #child').attr('id', 'modifyChildId');  
$('div#parent' > 'div#child').attr('id', 'modifyChildId');  
$('div#parent').find('div#child').attr('id', 'modifyChildId');
```

I understand that I can change the id by using child id itself, like:

```
$('div#child').attr('id', 'modifyChildId');
```

but the scenario here is:
I have two child elements with same id, such as:

```
    <div id="global_parent">  
        <div id = "child">  
        </div>  
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
    .

    <div id="parent">  
        <div id = "child">  
        </div>  
    </div>
```

and I have to change the id of child div of parent.

Comment: Sorry which one would you like to change? or both?

Comment: just second one would be enough, i.e., considering last example: using parent id I need to change the child id, not the child of global_parent

Comment: Should be able to use $('#parent > #child').attr('id', 'modifyChildId');  then

Comment: @SurendraSingh This is exactly the reason why it is completely invalid HTML to have duplicated ids **all ids must be unique** When JavaScript searches for a specific id it will stop searching after it finds the first one. You must change one of the `#child` divs. You will get unexpected results at best if you persist to use invalid code.

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('#parent> #child').attr('id', 'modifyChildId');
```

Another option is to use `find()` method:

```
$('#parent').find('#child').attr('id', 'modifyChildId');
```

> `.find()` method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Comment: $('#parent').find('#child').attr('id', 'modifyChildId'); // this worked for me, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

`$('#parent').find('#child').attr('id', 'modifyChildId');`

Answer (score 0):

You should never have two elements on your page with the same ID.

You should instead use classes

```
<div id="global_parent">  
        <div class="child">  
        </div>  
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
    .

    <div id="parent">  
        <div class="child">  
        </div>  
    </div>
```

And then use the selector `$("#parent > .child")` instead

Answer (score 0):

From the context of your question, I understand that you're inserting DOM elements into the `div#parent`.

When this happens, jQuery is unable to detect the newly inserted element. If you have the `div#parent` present when the page is loaded, then try this:

```
 $("#parent").find("#child").attr('id', 'modifiedChildId')})
```

If you don't have the `div#parent` present, then try this:

`$(document).find("#parent").find("#child").attr('id', 'modifiedChildId')})`